# PostgreSQL - How to make an auto-increment function that follows the row number?

Tags: postgresql

I'm having a trouble finding an option to keep an auto-increment function that follows the column number/ID without having a whole complicated process. Is there a data-type like serial/identity that keeps track of the column ID, but also tracks it when it deletes it? 
[Here's what happens when I delete values (20) from a table and the ID doesn't match the row number anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylq0r.png).

Comment: A sequence. Create a sequence and use it with nextval every time you need the next value

Comment: Does it work even if I delete values? Let's say I initially had 40 values, then deleted the 22nd, wouldn't it still give 41 after?

Comment: Why would you need to keep it that way? More often than not, row id won't match sequence number for any database. Database won't get things in a specific order (unless you specify it) and that is even more visible in high concurrence scenarios. Also, no IDENTITY / SEQUENCE set up available will track deleting IDs as you requested because they just keep the next value available. In your scenario, you'd need to check which IDs are deleted and filling them before using new IDs.

Comment: Because in my scenario the ID gets filled up very fast and it becomes a pain to call on it every time. That was my initial question, if there isn't an easy solution then it's fine, thanks though

Comment: Sorry if the last comment came through as too blunt, just tried to detail conditions of such situation. Main problem is: if you delete things in the middle, it's a whole additional task to keep track of unused IDs, adding work to your workflow. Because moving sequence back would work for that value and then, its next value should be moved to the next empty value. In a table with hundreds of millons, that by itself might use a lot of your DB I/O. That's why I asked, it is not trivial and perhaps there are functional requirements you might solve in another way